# LDAP in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ldap

Working with a LDAP server through Visual Studio 2010, the code I have here implicates this import:

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
```

But this import apparently doesn't exist in VS 10. It gives no errors but it gives me a warning and also the rest of the code to the connection becomes invalid because it needs to recon the import to work. Has anyone have ever worked with this and it's certain on how to get it up and running?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not figured this out by now, what I think you are saying is that you get a "compiler error" because the reference does not exist

I think you need to add the reference to System.DirectoryServices DLL to your project.

Try adding a project reference in visual studio to the DLL located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.DirectoryServices.dll

Hope this helps.